# Platform Channels is not returning swift closure on initial run

Tags: swift, flutter, closures, firebase-cloud-messaging, cross-platform

I am developing a Flutter application where I need to utilise the native Firebase Messaging plugin for each platform. I have followed Flutter's guide on [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to be able to implement native code. My problem is, that when I install the application on any iOS device for the first time the platform channels is not receiving anything from Swift. The methodCall leaves me hanging. However, when the application is re-installed the token is returned. I am fairly new to Swift and apparently have a hard time fully grasping how to properly implement closures and the @escaping parameter.

I have narrowed the problem down to the line `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)` (which is pretty important for a Flutter application). When the line is left out I retrieve the token every time, but the splash screen is never presented (the app is stalling at a blank screen, which is not viable solution).

At first I thought the application was affected by the fact it request permissions to show notifications on the initial run, but even when I do not answer the pop-up before re-installing the application I get the token. I tried running the application without requesting permissions to show notifications, but this did not affect the outcome.

**Client / Flutter**

The following code is called from initState():

```
  Future<void> getTokenNatively() async {
    print("inside getTokenNatively()");
    try {
      userToken = await getFirebaseTokenChannel.invokeMethod("getTokenNatively");
      print("-- FLUTTER -- userToken: $userToken");
    } catch (error) {
      print("getTokenNatively() resulted in an error: $error");
    } finally {
      print("Finally has run.");
    }
  }
```

**Host / iOS**

The following method is called inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
            let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
            let tokenChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.example.obscured/getTokenNatively",
                                                    binaryMessenger: controller)

            tokenChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
                [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
                print("just inside our FlutterMethodCall closure")
                guard call.method == "getTokenNatively" else {
                    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                    return
                }

                print("I will be printed every time")

                InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID(handler: { (res, error) in
                    print("First line after 'in' inside InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID")
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
                        result(error.localizedDescription)
                    } else if let res = res {
                        print("Remote instance ID token: \(res.token)")
                        result(res.token)
                    } else {
                        print("neither a error or result. What are you?")
                        result("none of the above")
                    }
                    print("Outside if/else if/else")
                })

                print("That seems to be the case for me as well")
            })

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

**Log for a fresh install (the app is not already loaded onto the device):**

```
2019-03-29 10:47:39.215103+0100 Runner[2334:1001337] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50101000 started
2019-03-29 10:47:39.215323+0100 Runner[2334:1001337] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see "some fancy google link")
2019-03-29 10:47:39.219380+0100 Runner[2334:1001347] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:60398/
APNs token retrieved: 32 bytes
2019-03-29 10:47:39.953629+0100 Runner[2334:1001340] flutter: didChangeDependencies() root_page
2019-03-29 10:47:39.959653+0100 Runner[2334:1001340] flutter: getDevice() result: IOS
2019-03-29 10:47:39.960416+0100 Runner[2334:1001340] flutter: inside getTokenNatively()
just inside our FlutterMethodCall closure
I will be printed every time
That seems to be the case for me as well
2019-03-29 10:47:40.177060+0100 Runner[2334:1001340] flutter: _authStatus: AuthStatus.signedIn
2019-03-29 10:47:40.177195+0100 Runner[2334:1001340] flutter: _homeStatus: null
2019-03-29 10:47:41.174878+0100 Runner[2334:1001340] flutter: Has [USER] accepted an invitation? Answer: true
2019-03-29 10:47:41.175041+0100 Runner[2334:1001340] flutter: crudMethods.hasHome(): true
2019-03-29 10:47:43.853516+0100 Runner[2334:1001355] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x1133cd2b0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-03-29 10:47:43.853858+0100 Runner[2334:1001355] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C4.1:2][0x1133cd2b0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-03-29 10:47:43.854425+0100 Runner[2334:1001355] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
2019-03-29 10:47:43.854485+0100 Runner[2334:1001355] TIC Read Status [4:0x0]: 1:57
```

**Log for a clean install when leaving the following line out `GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)`:**

```
2019-03-29 10:45:37.212943+0100 Runner[2327:1000780] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:60265/
2019-03-29 10:45:37.214168+0100 Runner[2327:1000766] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50101000 started
2019-03-29 10:45:37.214855+0100 Runner[2327:1000766] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see "some shortened Google url")
APNs token retrieved: 32 bytes
2019-03-29 10:45:37.636480+0100 Runner[2327:1000772] [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firestore#settings on channel plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore)
#0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:300:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      Firestore.settings (file:///Users/[USER]/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.9.5+2/lib/src/firestore.dart:145:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      main (package:cue_app/main.dart:31:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:189:25)
#4      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#5      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#6      _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#7      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1500:12)
#8      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:180:5)
#9      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/lib/isolate_patch.dart:300:19)
#10     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/lib/isolate_patch.dart:171:12)
Firebase registration token: [OMITTED]
```

I am then getting the token, but the app never presents the splash screen (hence, it is not a solution).

**Log for a re-install (An earlier version of the application is on the device):**

```
2019-03-29 11:30:28.125256+0100 Runner[2345:1004655] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.50101000 started
2019-03-29 11:30:28.127196+0100 Runner[2345:1004655] 5.7.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see "some google link")
2019-03-29 11:30:28.133468+0100 Runner[2345:1004666] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:61630/
APNs token retrieved: 32 bytes
2019-03-29 11:30:28.590713+0100 Runner[2345:1004661] flutter: didChangeDependencies() root_page
2019-03-29 11:30:28.595299+0100 Runner[2345:1004661] flutter: getDevice() result: IOS
2019-03-29 11:30:28.596043+0100 Runner[2345:1004661] flutter: inside getTokenNatively()
just inside our FlutterMethodCall closure
I will be printed every time
That seems to be the case for me as well
First line after 'in' inside InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID
Remote instance ID token: [OMITTED]
Outside if/else if/else
2019-03-29 11:30:28.794378+0100 Runner[2345:1004661] flutter: _authStatus: AuthStatus.signedIn
2019-03-29 11:30:28.794446+0100 Runner[2345:1004661] flutter: _homeStatus: null
2019-03-29 11:30:28.796259+0100 Runner[2345:1004661] flutter: -- FLUTTER -- userToken: [OMITTED]
2019-03-29 11:30:28.796293+0100 Runner[2345:1004661] flutter: Finally has run.
2019-03-29 11:30:29.974120+0100 Runner[2345:1004661] flutter: Has [USER] accepted an invitation? Answer: true
2019-03-29 11:30:29.974453+0100 Runner[2345:1004661] flutter: crudMethods.hasHome(): true
```

**UPDATE**

I have simplified the example. The Swift code is from [Firebase's repo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios). When I run their example as a stand alone it works as a charm. However, when I try to integrate it in my Flutter project it breaks it the various scenarios outlined above.

For some reason the code is not allowed to return the code within the methodChannel on the first run. I think it has something to do with @escaping in Swift, but I do not know how to progress from here. Has anybody got an idea?